# Jquery "this" keyword returns entire window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, this

I'm new to Jquery, and I'm trying to figure out how to use the "this" keyword.
When I try to test it using a simple button with a console log, it keeps giving me the entire window object.  Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I just want "this" to return the button.

`

```
$("button").on("click", (e) => {
    console.log(this)
    console.log($(this))
})
```

`
This is what I tried. and here is what it gives me in the console log:

[image: What I'm getting in console log]

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is the Window object. At least, I'm sure this isn't my button.

Comment: Use `function (e) {` instead

Comment: Or stick with the arrow function and use `e.target` instead of `this`